# Android error, failed to set top app changed

Tags: android

Can somebody please throw some light on the arcane error "Failed to
set top app changed", by the activity manager?
I'm wondering what causes this error. In one of my application I'm
making a view fullscreen and then switching back. For the first time
things are ok but then if i try to make the view full screen again, I
get a crash and the error mentioned above is found on logcat.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Reagrds,
M

Comment: The crash log and the actual error text would be helpful.

Comment: I am Having this problem too. At this moment I can only reproduce it on a handset, not during debugging: using 'aLogCat' I can see the only thing in the errorlog is: "activity manager: fail to set top app changed!". If I can find more information I might open a new question with some more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encountered this problem today myself.. let me tell you what did the trick for me... maybe it will help you too.

anyway in my case it crashed because i overrided onActivityResult and inside that event i tried to do this:

```
Bundle extra = data.getExtras();
    String albumId = extra.getString("id");
```

this is old code that got left in the application.. after deleting this everything worked as expected.

hope this helps in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my app, the activity crashed and "activity manager: fail to set top app changed!" in logs. Turned out to be one line of code in the onPause caused the problem. Check your onPause method of the Activity that launches the new Activity to see if something should not be done there. I think there could be many reasons causing this problem, but the basic idea is that the launching activity does something wrong when the new Activity is going to show up.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that i change orientation on activity start and needed to add android:configChanges="orientation" , like this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".RiskniMilionActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```